# Proper way to format tables for HTML in PHP method

Tags: php, html

I seem to be having trouble formatting tables for my Search Form.

What i need is proper formatting to display when the search form returns results.

Quick Question: is this the proper way to format Tables using the HTML in PHP method...... i seem to be off by a little.

---

```
 "<table>";
echo "<td>";
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<tr>";

echo "<th><div class='searchresults'>"   .   $title  .  "</th></div>"; 
echo "<br/>";
echo "<th><div class='searchresults'>" .  $model .  "</th></div>";
echo "<br/>";
echo  "<div class='image'><img src =" . $image . "></table></div></a>";
echo "<br/>";

echo "</tr>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: No, this looks quite messy. Why not just echo the php-variable in your html ?
Or even better try to use a template engine.

Comment: you have opened ans closed table tr,td,div tags how ever you want. So please go through some tutorials.

Comment: I think you should learn html syntax if you can't tell what is wrong with the above

Answer (score 5):

**Start from scratch.** This code is messy lacks any sort of `HTML` structure.

Whether you wrote it yourself or you have adapted someone else's code, **you need to completely rewrite it**.

---

```
"<tables>";
```

Is this being `echo`ed? What is this string?

---

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<tr>";
```

You have too many opening `<tr>` tags. Rows shouldn't be contained within rows.

---

```
echo "<th><div class='searchresults'>"   .   $title  .  "</th></div>";
```

This isn't chronological. `<th><div>content</th></div>` - you should make it `<th><div>content</div></th>`, keeping the `div` contained within the `th`. But you shouldn't really be using a `div` inside the `th` at all - use CSS to edit the style of that cell.

---

```
echo "<br/>";
```

Why is this here? You don't need this. If you want the cell to be taller, change the CSS.

---

```
echo "<th><div class='searchresults'>" .  $model .  "</th></div>";
```

Check your order here too.

---

```
echo "<br/>";
```

Again, not necessary.

---

```
echo  "<div class='image'><img src =" . $image . "></table></div></a>";
```

So much wrong here.

- This `div` isn't part of the table.
- The `img src` isn't contained within double OR single quotes so is invalid HTML.
- Why are you closing the table here? `</table>` should be at the end of the table.
- What is the `</a>` tag closing? There's no opening `<a>` tag anywhere in your code. It's just bizarre.

---

```
echo "<br/>";
```

Again, not necessary.

---

```
"</tr>";
"</td>";
"</table>";
"</div>";
```

There's no coherent order to any of this. They're not part of an `echo` or `print` command, they're not chronological, what is the `</div>` closing?

Answer (score 2):

I think I would go this way:

```
<?php
    $title = 'title';
    $model = 'model';
    $image = 'image';
?>
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div class='searchresults'><?php echo $title; ?></div>
            </th>           
            <th>
                <div class='searchresults'><?php echo $model; ?></div></th>
            <th>
                <div class='image'><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" /></div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

If the html-markup is bigger than the one shown I would consider to use a template enginge. There plenty of these which can be used with PHP (e.g. [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) or [mustache](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php))

Comment: There's always a slight performance trade-off with template engines though and really, are they *that* much simpler to read, when outputting variables, than `<?= $title; ?>` ?

Comment: The only thing I would say about this is I think the three columns are meant to be in one row, but I may be wrong as there seems to be a closing div after each column.

Comment: @CD001 Yes you're right. But I just want to mention the possibility as they make sense when the code is getting bigger and encapsulated.

Answer (score 0):

```
    echo"
    <table>

    <tr>


    <td class='searchresults'>"   .   $title  .  "</td> 

    <td class='searchresults'>" .  $model .  "</td>

    <td class='image'><img src =" . $image . "></td>

    </tr>

    </table>
    ";
```

I think this is correct way!!

Comment: `HTML` structure is not looks okay

Comment: @Sachink check it out! I thought u want html in php so i correct only php format but right now both format is correct

Comment: my fault but wiyhout that it will work fine

Comment: @Sachink if it's working then accept it!